# set Mac OS PATH

Tags: macos, postgresql, path

1. the version of my Mac OS is 10.12.5
2. I have add the path "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin" in the file in "/etc/paths", just like the following picture
   [I have add the path in /etc/paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbS4g.png)

However, when I print $PATH in terminal:
[there is no such a path "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin" in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwwZj.png)
there is no such a path "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin" in $PATH

Comment: I just want to make "psql" a valid command. Now it shows "cammond not found" when I type  psql in the terminal

Comment: please post exact command you ran to add psql to PATH

Comment: I add psql to Path through vi

Comment: Then just relogin. Or execute .profile or whatever you edited